# blank page on Facebook App

Tags: facebook

We make our Facebook application. Everything was all normal. After I rename one file, all the links do not work anymore. This was not a problem earlier in our application. I have no idea why this is happening.

Any thoughts? If more info is needed, please let me know.

[This is my application](https://www.facebook.com/sensitif/app_499841173364800)

Answer (score 0):

Your application here:
http://www.hamilgakhamil.com/sensitifstory/like

missing an image ([link](http://www.hamilgakhamil.com/sensitifstory/images/banner-fb.jpg)) on `images/banner-fb.jpg`, and the css files also.
To fix this move the `css` and `images` directories in the application root directory `sensitifstory`.